# Calculating Valid Moves for Hexagonal Chess Pieces in Python

Tags: python, offset, chess, hexagonal-tiles

Currently I'm experiencing dificulties with calculating the valid moves for pieces in my implementation of hexagonal chess in python. Let me first begin with describing how the movement of the knight is defined in Hexagonal chess.

Let me focus on 1 movement action of the knight. A knight move 4 rows up and 1 column to the left. This is described in the following lines of code:

```
target = (position_col - 1, position_row - 4)  
if on_board(target): 
    if empty_hexagon(target, board) or piece_color_on_position(target, board) != self.color: 
          move = Move(self, self.position, target) 
          self.moves.append(move)
```

Now this works for certain positions like here:

[image: Correct movement of a knight]

Now this does indeed work for this specific hexagon, but not for all. See for example this position:

[image: Incorrect movement of a knight]

This is happening because not all rows in my board contain the same amount of columns. My board is basically a 2 dimensional array filled with hexagon objects, which I don't think is particularly important in this example, but it has the following structure:

```
        self.board =  [
            [None],
            [None, None],
            [None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None,],
            [None, None],
            [None]
        ]
```

I would like to create an offset function that looks at my current row and the target row and calculates an offset such that I can just use my 'normal' steps of movement and calculate the corresponding target column. Is there a way to do this, or perhaps another coordinate system which I can use to do this more easily?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried a couple of things which I either didn't implement correctly.

I used a function to calculate differences in columns per row. If a my starting row contained 3 columns, while my target row contained 5 columns, than I added this difference to my target column. This however did not have the desired effect.

Edit 1*
The offset looked like the following:

```
offset = BOARD_LENGTH[position_row - 4] - BOARD_LENGTH[position_row]
        target = (position_col - 1 + offset, position_row - 4)
        if on_board(target):
            if empty_hexagon(target, board) or piece_color_on_position(target, board) != self.color:
                move = Move(self, self.position, target)
                self.moves.append(move)
```

where `BOARD_LENGTH = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,6,6,5,4,3,2,1]`(these are the amount of hexagons per row in my 2d board list.)

This implementation of an offset didn't have the desired effect, because calculating the valid moves of the pieces still gave me incorrect squares to move to for a lot of starting positions.

Edit 2*
Since it from my original screenshots it looked like the knight was not moving 4 rows up and 1 column to the right. I'll add a screenshot here to show my coordinate system. Here we can see that we are in fact moving 4 rows up.Since we are using hexagons the hexagon directly on top of a hexagon is not 1 row up, but 2 rows up. Hopefully this screenshot will clarify this:

[The coordinates of the board printed on each hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7QP9.jpg)

Comment: `I've tried a couple of things which I either didn't implement correctly.` please show your code

Comment: Neither of those images look like "4 rows up and 1 column to the left" to me.  I suggest you draw your board, label each of the positions with coordinates, and determine mathematically the valid moves BEFORE you try to write code to implement that.

Comment: I agree with @Joe, the first image looks like "2 rows up and 2 columns left" to me.

Comment: Hi @MarcinOrlowski thanks for your response. I've added some information in my question. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Joe and thomaoc

Thanks for your replies! I've added a screenshot with the boards coordinates printed on the hexagons. Hopefully this clarifies that the knight indeed moves up 4 hexagons, but that the columns look somewhat random to me.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use those coordinates, but if that's what you're using, can you say which positions are valid to move to from (10,2)? Then can you give a mathematical formula that gives those positions?  Does that formula also work for (12,3)? And (9,2)? If so, then try implementing it in code.

Comment: I'd use coordinates with the same row coordinate as you use, but have the column coordinates match the actual columns as seen in the diagram. Then, not knowing anything about hex-chess, I think there are three different possible knight-moves, one of them being "row plus or minus 1 and column plus or minus 3".

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254655/hexagon-grid-coordinate-system for some ideas for your coordinate system. Using one of the systems explored in that post will make finding neighbours way easier and will probably help you in the long run

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I think I have found an answer here thanks to Joe. First of all thanks everyone for taking a look at this problem. I'll post my solution here if someone else needs to look for a solution to this (or a similar) problem in the future.

Looking at the coordinate system that I used the task of formulating a formula that works would be impossible for me. Therefore I've changed the coordinate system to the following:

[image: New board coordinates]

Instead of starting each hexagon on our board at 0, we imagine that there are hexagons to the left and right of this hexagon. At position (0,3) we imagine there being 3 hexagons to the left of it, and 2 hexagons to the right of it. Our board therefore now looks like:

```
   self.board =  [
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None]
    ]
```

Note* not all elements of this 2 dimensional list are populated with hexagons.

The problem is now more easy to understand. It looks like there is currently only a mismatch between even and uneven rows. If we go from an even row to an uneven row we see that the same column index is to the right of that same index in the even row. That is to say, if we have row 10, with column 3. If we were to move to row 9 column 3 we would move up one row and go to the right. This can be seen in the coordinate system shared in the screenshot above.

Now I currently only looked at the single movement action of the knight. For this I changed the code to:

```
    knight_offset = calculate_offset(position_row, position_row - 5)
    target = (position_col - knight_offset, position_row - 5)
    if on_board(target, board):
        if empty_hexagon(target, board) or piece_color_on_position(target, board) != self.color:
            move = Move(self, self.position, target)
            self.moves.append(move)
```

And I added the following helper function to deal with the offset:

```
def calculate_offset(start_row, target_row):
    ''' 
    This function calculates the offset that should be used to move from hex A, to hex B
    '''
    if start_row % 2 == 0 and target_row % 2 == 1:
        return 1
    return 0
```

And this seems to be working for this single knight movement. As can be seen from the following screenshot (I also tested this for other positions, but this seems to be working):

[image: Knight Movement Correct]

It could be that  I will have to do some more tinkering with different movements and offsets for different pieces, especially moving to the left of the board and to the right of the board. However, according to me this issue has been resolved and I have a way forward again. Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: Which plotting library and colors did you use for your images?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The library which I use for displaying my hexagons, board and pieces is pygame. Since I can't leave quite a big comment here let me link my [Github repo](https://github.com/mattijsgietman/Hexagon-Chess/tree/main). `def draw_hexagon(surface, color, position, width=0):
` and `def draw_board(surface, color_board):` can be found in the draw.py file. All my capital variable names can be found in the CONST.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use different column indices for the columns than the posted answer - ones for which hexagons had the same column indices if and only if they were vertically aligned.

```
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon
import numpy as np

a = np.sqrt(3)/2
colors = ['brown', 'darkkhaki', 'gold']

hexagons = {}
for i in range(21):
    for j in range(11):
        if (((i+j) % 2 == 1) and (5 <= i+j <= 25) and (-5 <= i-j <= 15)):
            hexagons[(i,j)] = {'center':(-7.5 + 1.5*j, (10-i)*a)}
        

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')

for idx in hexagons:
    xy = hexagons[idx]['center']

    # add patch
    this_patch = RegularPolygon(xy, 
                                numVertices=6, 
                                radius=1, 
                                orientation=np.pi/6,
                                alpha=0.2, 
                                facecolor=colors[idx[0] % 3],
                                edgecolor='k',
                               )
    ax.add_patch(this_patch)
    plt.text(xy[0], xy[1], str(idx), ha='center', va='center')
plt.autoscale(enable = True)
plt.savefig("hex_chess.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: Hexagonal Chess Board with indices]

Using these indices, the position of the center of a hexagon with indices `(i,j)` is given by:

```
a = np.sqrt(3)/2
(x,y) = (-7.5 + 1.5*j, (10-i)*a)
```

The rule for valid knight moves from position `(i1, j1)` to `(i2, j2)` is:

```
((abs(i1-i2)==1 and abs(j1-j2)==3) or 
 (abs(i1-i2)==5 and abs(j1-j2)==1) or 
 (abs(i1-i2)==4 and abs(j1-j2)==2))
```

Which is all of the hexagons with:

```
(x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 == 21
```

A function to check whether a move is valid could be defined as:

```
def move_valid(start, end, piece):
    """Check whether a move from start to end is valid for piece.

    start : Tuple[int, int]
        The (row, column) of the starting position.
    end : Tuple[int, int]
        The (row, column) of the ending position.
    piece : str
        The type of piece, e.g. 'knight'.

    """
    (i1, j1) = start
    (i2, j2) = end
    
    # check if start and end are on the board
    if start not in hexagons or end not in hexagons:
        return False
    
    if piece == 'knight':
        valid = ((abs(i1-i2)==1 and abs(j1-j2)==3) or 
                 (abs(i1-i2)==5 and abs(j1-j2)==1) or 
                 (abs(i1-i2)==4 and abs(j1-j2)==2))
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
        
    return valid
```

For example, the valid moves from the center hexagon are:

```
this_hexagon = (10,5)
this_center = hexagons[this_hexagon]['center']

for h in hexagons:
    if move_valid(this_hexagon, h, 'knight'):
        dist_sq = ((this_center[0] - hexagons[h]['center'][0])**2 + 
                   (this_center[1] - hexagons[h]['center'][1])**2)
        print(f"{h}: {dist_sq}")
```

with output:

```
(5, 4): 20.999999999999996
(5, 6): 20.999999999999996
(6, 3): 21.0
(6, 7): 21.0
(9, 2): 21.0
(9, 8): 21.0
(11, 2): 21.0
(11, 8): 21.0
(14, 3): 21.0
(14, 7): 21.0
(15, 4): 20.999999999999996
(15, 6): 20.999999999999996
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. reviewing your reasoning I agree that this would be a better coordinate system especially when implementing other piece movement. I do think that the way you are creating the movement for the knight is a bit too abstract for me to completely understand, but from looking at the coordinate system I'm pretty sure that this will be something that I can implement myself.